# How to read the new XStreamConverter parameters?

Tags: xml-serialization, marshalling, xstream

Since version 1.4.2 of XStream, the XStreamConverter annotation takes additional parameters (very good feature and just what I need).

```
@XStreamConverter(value=CustomXStreamConverter.class, strings={xyz"})
private List<String> phones;
```

But how can I read this values (xyz) in my custom converter?

```
public class CustomXStreamConverter implements Converter {
    //?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the solution, just override the class constructor in order to receive the parameter.

```
public class CustomXStreamConverter implements Converter {

private String alias;

public ListToStringXStreamConverter(String alias) {
    super();
    this.alias = alias; //xyz
}
//...
```